# Use DCMTK to as library to create cloud-based PACS

Tags: dcmtk

I'm quite new to `DCMTK` and wish to create a `PACS` with Cassandra as backed-database.

The `PACS` should support `FIND-SCP, MOVE-SCP, STORE-SCP, GET-SCP protocol`. Please tell me where (class, documentation,...) to begin!

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier if you could ask more specifically...

Online documentation is available here: http://support.dcmtk.org/docs-snapshot/

In order to understand how to build the various SCPs, I would recommend to look into the sample applications, e.g. storescp and dcmqrscp. A good starting point could also be the [DcmSCP](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs-snapshot/classDcmSCP.html) and [DcmStorageSCP](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs-snapshot/classDcmStorageSCP.html) class.